# Use MsDeploy with MsDeployAgentService to deploy to a specific site

Tags: iis, msdeploy

I am trying to deploy a site from a folder to my web server using MsDeploy.  The web server has the MsDeployAgentService installed.  I was able to deploy the site using the following command to msdeploy.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:dirPath=C:\src\website -dest:auto,computerName='http://192.168.0.2/MsDeployAgentService',userName=Administrator,password=xxxxxx
```

However, I can't figure out were the files were deployed to on the server.  I would like to deploy the files to a specific site on the web server rather than the 'Default Web Site'

What is the msdeploy switch or option for specifying the destination site on the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using the Web Deploy '[contentPath](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569034%28WS.10%29.aspx)' provider for both the -source and -dest.  The working command looks like this:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath=C:\src\website -dest:contentPath="d:\sites\mywebsite",computerName='http://192.168.0.2/MsDeployAgentService',userName=Administrator,password=xxxxxx
```

Comment: +1 You rock! I've been working on this issue for hours. Thank you for posting the command!